# Flex column replacement for unsupported browsers

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been trying to get my head managing a specific layout without using flexbox (specifically flex-direction: column). I'm almost certain this has been asked elsewhere but for the life of me I haven't been able to find it, so I'm very sorry if it has and will gladly close if anyone can show me it answered somewhere else.

The problem is this: given an arbitrary number of divs, all but one of which have a fixed height, how can I lay them out in a column such that the remaining element fills 100% of the height available to it, after the others have been taken into account?

It looks like ([Codepen](http://codepen.io/unwttng/pen/VvwOoZ)):

```
div.container
  div.cell.fixedheight
  div.cell.fillheight
  div.cell.fixedheight
  div.cell.fixedheight
  div.cell.fixedheight
```

This is pretty easily achievable using flexbox with something like:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.fixedheight {height: 20px;}
.fillheight {flex: 1;}
```

But I'm essentially not in a position to use flexbox, since supporting older browsers is necessary here.

**Edit** when I say I can't use flexbox, I mean not even vendor prefixes :(

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no alternative...that's why flexbox was created. Other than that you're looking at a JS solution....although a single column table *might* do something but it sounds like a tough sell.

Comment: Single column 'display: table'-type designs were where I was thinking this would go, wondered if anyone had any more expertise with that than me...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with table layouts, with a light wrapper of row-style and cell-style divs. If anyone knows of a solution that doesn't involve an extra wrapper in the markup I'll gladly take it :)

See the approach on this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/unwttng/pen/zvYVOM) but I'll put the relevant code here:

```
div.container
  div.row.fixedheight
    div.cell
  div.row.fillheight
    div.cell
  div.row.fixedheight
    div.cell
  div.row.fixedheight
    div.cell
  div.row.fixedheight
    div.cell
```

and then the CSS:

```
.container {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row.fixedheight {
  height: 20px;
}

.row.fillheight {}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

The `.cell`s will accept very little further styling (margins etc) so they'll need to act as a wrapper for whatever richly styled divs you want to put inside them.

Also note that multiple `.fillheight`s will share the available height between them equally.

**Also** note that the fixed height rows are not in fact fixed height - the 20px will be used as effectively a min-height, but the cell will wrap whatever it has in it. I've been accepting this and setting height: 0 on the cell and height: 20px on an inner div which isn't table-styled.